# TabView causing preview to crash

Tags: swiftui, xcode12, tabview

I am currently trying to make a featured games section in my app. I am using the TabView in SwiftUI to do this, but am running into an issue where the preview crashes from it. I am not getting any errors and also am unable to run it live. Below is the code of the view causing the preview crash.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeaturedGamesView: View {
    var numberOfImages: Int
    @ObservedObject var featuredGames: GameQuery
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    
    var body: some View {
     
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Featured")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                              .padding(.top, 1)
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                          TabView() {
                                ForEach(featuredGames.games.results) { game in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLazyView(GameDetailsView(gameDetailsQuery: GameQuery(gameName: game.slug)))){
                                        GameItem(game: game)
                                    }
                                  }
                              }
                              .offset(x: (CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * -185), y: 0)
                              .animation(.spring())
                              .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                                  self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex + 1) % 19
                              }
                              
                          }
                          .frame(height: 200)
                          .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                          .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                          
                      
                  }
    }
}



struct FeaturedGamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FeaturedGamesView(numberOfImages: 3, featuredGames: GameQuery(gameCategory: GameCategory.featured))
    }
}
```

From some of my experimentation it seems to either not like the observable object I am using to get an array of data to populate the tabview. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I created a simpler example which still produces the error. In this case everything is generic except the array being used which is an observable object. Switching out the data structure used in the ForEach fixes it, but am looking to understand why my observable object does not work here.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @ObservedObject var featuredGames: GameQuery
     
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Featured")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                                  .padding(.top, 1)
                HStack {
                    TabView() {
                        ForEach(featuredGames.games.results) { game in
                            Text("Hi")
                        }
                    }.frame(height: 170)
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
                    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    
                }
            }
     
        }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test(featuredGames: GameQuery(gameCategory: GameCategory.featured))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code.

I fixed below part to simple then it works.

Maybe this has a problem.

```
ForEach(featuredGames.games.results) { game in
                                NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLazyView(GameDetailsView(gameDetailsQuery: GameQuery(gameName: game.slug)))){
                                    GameItem(game: game)
                                }
                              }
```

Working code (I made my self simple GameQuery observableObject)

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeaturedGamesView: View {
    var numberOfImages: Int
    @ObservedObject var featuredGames: GameQuery
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()


var body: some View {
 
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Featured")
            .font(.headline)
            .padding(.leading, 15)
                          .padding(.top, 1)
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                      TabView() {
                        ForEach(featuredGames.results, id:\.self) { game in
                                NavigationLink(destination: VStack {}){
                                    Text("Hello")
                                }
                              }
                          }
                          .offset(x: (CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * -185), y: 0)
                          .animation(.spring())
                          .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                              self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex + 1) % 19
                          }
                          
                      }
                      .frame(height: 200)
                      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                  

    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                          
                      
                  }
    }
}

final class GameQuery: ObservableObject {
    var gameCagetory: Int = 0
    var results: [Int] = [1,2,3]
}

struct FeaturedGamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FeaturedGamesView(numberOfImages: 3, featuredGames: GameQuery())
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the array of data I am feeding it, but I am not sure why. If I remove usage of the array and add the simple example you provided it works, but this does not solve my problem.